# FileProvider exception : IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-image, android-fileprovider

I want to open camera, click and upload the full image to a server. For that, I'm trying to save the image to a location and then upload it from another method. I have been receiving this error in getting the `fileprovider` to work, and have tried various stack overflow solutions but none seem to work for me.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.learning.speeeddy.imagereader.app/files/Pictures/IMG_20180627_132113_1596259289.jpg
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:738)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
    at com.learning.speeeddy.imagereader.feature.MainActivity.dispatchTakePictureIntent(MainActivity.java:67)
    at com.learning.speeeddy.imagereader.feature.MainActivity.access$200(MainActivity.java:40)
    at com.learning.speeeddy.imagereader.feature.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:323)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

In MainActivity.java

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(pictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        //Create a file to store the image
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.learning.speeeddy.imagereader.fileprovider", photoFile);
            pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp =
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                    Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir =
            getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );


    return image;
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.learning.speeeddy.imagereader">
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="aia-compat-api-min-version"
            android:value="1" />
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.learning.speeeddy.imagereader.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

In file_paths.xml (/res/xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.learning.speeeddy.imagereader.app/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Comment: put path="." in file_paths.xml

Comment: Tried that already @ShwetaChauhan along with some more variations, including writing full path, and other tags like external-file-path, root-path with suitable paths

Comment: Can you not open camera, receive image on return, then upload image from memory or storage? https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics You're already using startActivityForResult() so you should get it on return anyway and can just use it from there. Don't need file_paths xml manifest garbage =)

Comment: @CmosBattery I was doing that earlier, but the resulting image is very small (thumbnail) and unfit for my consumption